# Any one their to help me to solve this relative velocity question?

Tags: kinematics

Two rail tracks ,which make an angle $X$ with  each other ,intersect  at  $O$. Two trains $P$  and $Q$ are travelling on these tracks with speeds $u$ and $v$ towards $O$. Initially $P$ & $Q$ are at distance $a$ & $b$ from $O$ respectively. Show that the shortest distance between the train is

$\frac{(av - bu)\sin X}{(u^2+v^2-2uv \cos X)}$

And show that trains would collide if

$\frac{u}{v} = \frac{a}{b}$

A clear  explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Shortest distance  = $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2\cdot a\cdot b\cdot cos(x)}$

Comment: Can u describe it further ?

Comment: I can describe it, but what you have to prove is  not the shortest distance actually, it is the rate of change of that shortest distance, which you can immediately see by differentiating this equation. So your question is not much clear, that whether you are asking shortest distance, or instantaneous rate of change of that distance.